# What is my laptop screen mode based on the stickers I see on the back of it?

Tags: laptop, display

I am trying to buy the correct screen for my laptop, as the current screen is broken and needs to be replaced.

Here is a picture of the sticker on the back of my laptop screen:

[image]

The data in the image is:

- P000605990
- WKE28
- LP156WF4 (SP)(J1)
- CT:CXXXX012B6U1UC
- 156D6EFT010M3 TR3MN
- LG Display
- RoHS Verified

I was told that I need the EXACT correct screen model number, otherwise it might not work.

Which number in this picture is the screen model number? Is it LP156WF4(SP)(J1) ?

I found one online which is the same except it has B1 instead of J1 at the end.

Answer (score 5):

It helps us a lot if you turn it upside down.

[image]

A [quick internet search](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=LG%20display%20part%20numbers&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=RuLlWPr7Eqjl8Afa86ywDA#q=LG%20display%20panel%20part%20number) for "LG Display Part Numbers" [found this site that](http://www.laptopscreenonline.com/laptop-screen-part-number-13-w.asp) suggests that all LG panel part numbers start with LP.

In many cases, finding the service manual for the laptop model might suggest alternative models that may work for that specific laptop.